# Breeze validation messages are not production ready

Tags: validation, breeze

Breeze's default validation messages use the database field name as part of the displayed error message; such as, "EmpTeleNo is required".  Obviously, this probably shouldn't end up in the production version of our software.

But as we approach delivery of our software, it was hoped that this might be fixed, perhaps by inspecting the "Display" attribute from the model or something like that.  As far as I can tell, this issue still remains.

Has this problem been resolved or has anyone figured out a work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not YET well documented but you can simply set the 'displayName' property on any dataProperty and this will override the autogenerated display name and will be used for all validation messages for this property. So

```
var custType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Customer");
var dp = custType.getProperty("companyName");
dp.displayName = "My custom display name";
```

Also, see the "Customize the message templates" topic at the bottom of this page: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation.

There is also an item on the Breeze User Voice that requests something very similar to what you are asking for. Please vote for it.

https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions